# Broken Wi-Fi on Dell Inspiron 5567 and 17.10

Tags: wireless, dell, 17.10, atheros

I've brand new latop and freshly installed Ubuntu. But I can't change wifi networks. Whenver I try to "touch" (change network, disable) the wifi after boot, it gets stuck.

It also happened in installer. I wanted to connect to my 2 home networks, but after successfully connecting to the first one, attempt to connect to second resulted in frozen and unresponsive installer.

After I try to do something with wifi, even `ip addr` gets stuck.

I also can't get into gnome settings, probably because wifi is the first section.

Also, shutdown gets stuck on *Network Manager*, *WPA supplicant* and *Raise network interfaces* tasks.

The adapter is Atheros QCA9377 (rev 31)

Comment: It works in Fedora 26

Comment: Some data: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25832501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kernel problem. Installing kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.10/ fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Which kernel version did you install? I'm having a stability problem with the same Dell model and Ubuntu version.

Comment: Right now I'm running on normal kernels from repositories. They have the fix.